# Swift custom UITableViewCell label is always nil

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview, cocoa-touch, swift

I've been stuck with this problem for days, so I'd be really happy if someone could help.
I'm trying to create a dynamic UITableView, for which I created a custom UITableView subclass and I've created a custom UITableViewCell subclass as well, because I need several UILabels and a UIButton in each cell.
The cell is created, but the problem is that the value of the labels is always nil, hence the cell isn't displayed properly.
[This is](http://prntscr.com/6g91ig), how the storyboard looks like, and [this is](http://prntscr.com/6g924v) what I see while running the program.

Here's my UITableViewCell subclass:

```
import UIKit

class QuestionTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet var student: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var labDesk: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var topic: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var answers: UILabel!

}
```

and my UITableView subclass:

```
import UIKit

class QuestionViewController: UITableViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    @IBOutlet var table: UITableView!
     struct Question {
        var student: String
        var labDesk: String
        var topic: String
        var answered: String
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        table.estimatedRowHeight = 50
        table.dataSource = self
        table.delegate = self
        self.table.registerClass(QuestionTableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }

    override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell") as QuestionTableViewCell
        cell.student.text = "random string"
        cell.labDesk?.text = "25/A"
        cell.topic?.text = "string"
        cell.answers?.text = "3"
        return cell
    }
}
```

Comment: try dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) and make sure your cell id matches, and if the cell is not optional, you shouldn't have to use cell.labDesk?.text, just cell.labDesk.text

Comment: I already tried that and it gives my this exception: 2015-03-13 15:31:09.626 LABhelper[40046:5574601] *** Assertion failure in -[UITableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath:], /SourceCache/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-3318.16.14/UITableView.m:6116 This is how my function looks like after what you suggested if I got it right: var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as QuestionTableViewCell 

I didn't make them optional, but somehow they became optionals, so without the ? the build fails.

Answer (score 74):

Try removing `self.table.registerClass(QuestionTableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")`

Comment: Its working fine. But why we are removing this line bcz its registering the customcell rite?

Comment: @iApple because the class is already present in the interface builder.

Comment: I removed this line and mine worked. Kind of confusing why I didn't need it, my guess is setting the custom class in the Interface builder does the same function as registering the custom cell class?

Comment: This is correct and helped me find the solution to my issue at the following URL... my nib/custom cell was being registered incorrectly
https://gist.github.com/gonzalezreal/92507b53d2b1e267d49a

Comment: Wow, super helpful!  This was also my issue.  In my case it worked fine until I would scroll my CollectionView, a simple list of labels. As soon as I scrolled a new row into view it crashed with a nil value. Thank you!

Answer (score 29):

If you're using a cell with a nib then make sure that you are registering the cell with the table view using `registerNib:forCellReuseIdentifier:`. If the cell just has a class then use `registerClass:forCellReuseIdentifier:`.

Comment: If you are using a nib, the exact syntax that you will need is: `tableView.registerNib(UINib(nibName: "YOURNIBNAME", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "YOURREUSEID")`

Answer (score 8):

First, you don't have to register the class if it exists in Interface Builder.

Second, you should `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath` instead of `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier`.

Third, `UITableViewController` already has a property called `tableView` so there is no need to make an IBOutlet to `table` as UITableViewController already handles this. It also conforms to the `UITableViewDataSource` and `UITableViewDataSource` so these are extraneous.

Fourth, don't set the properties for `table` set them for `tableView`.

Fifth, `cell.labDesk.text = ""` is sufficient, no need to make it optional.

If all your IBOutlets are hooked up, Cell Identifiers correctly set, and these revisions are made, it will work.

```
class QuestionTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet var student: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var labDesk: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var topic: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var answers: UILabel!

}


class QuestionViewController: UITableViewController {

    struct Question {
        var student: String
        var labDesk: String
        var topic: String
        var answered: String
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 50
        tableView.dataSource = self
        tableView.delegate = self
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }

    override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell") as QuestionTableViewCell
        cell.student.text = "random string"
        cell.labDesk.text = "25/A"
        cell.topic.text = "string"
        cell.answers.text = "3"
        return cell
    }
}
```

Comment: What I already told you happens, if it isn't optional, it doesn't run.
cell.student.text = "random string"
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Comment: Does it not compile or does it crash as soon as it opens?

Comment: It crashes as soon as I reach the UITableView

Comment: Because this code works, so it could be your IBOutlets not properly connected

Comment: ah, you're using a view controller with a table view inside of it, note this is not a UITableViewController

Comment: The fix: Delete your view controller, replace it with a UITableViewController in interface builder, set its class to be QuestionViewController, reimplement the cell and reconnect the outlets and you should be good

Comment: It is a UITableViewController, I already deleted it and readded and then changed it's class to QuestionViewController

Answer (score 8):

The most important part is to register the xib containing the custom cell with the table view. Therefore add the following code in viewDidLoad() method.

```
let nib = UINib.init(nibName: "MyCustomCell", bundle: nil)    
self.tblUsers.register(nib, forCellReuseIdentifier: "MyCustomCell")
```

Answer (score 3):

I might be late here, but I just solved a similar problem.

Make sure you've set the Identifier in InterfaceBuilder on your UITableViewCell.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

For those who are still trying to figure this out after trying all those possible solutions:

Disconnect/Reconnect the IBOutlets in your Storyboards should do the trick!

Answer (score 1):

Don't forget to add:

```
tableView?.register(UINib(nibName: "xyz",
                           bundle: nil),
                    forCellReuseIdentifier: "abc")
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a table cell with Xib. you need to register your cell with ..

```
register(_:forCellReuseIdentifier:)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't added constraints for the label then they will not be created though the custom cell is created.
Make sure you added some constraints.

Comment: Welcome @NewBe on StackOverflow, It would really help others if you can attached some code snippet. For more detail on how to write good answer please visit https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the selected cell is in the right "`module`" and if necessary, inherit:

[image]

If not, your `IBOutlets` will be nil.

Answer (score -1):

Issue I was facing: TableViewCell has been created and all the IBOutlets are nil. So I can't set any values such as text or color etc. Below code worked for me.

Xcode version: 13.3

**Step 1:**
Remove **datasource** and **delegate** reference form storyboard.

**Step 2:**
In viewDidLoad add,

```
tableView.delegate = self
tableView.dataSource = self
```

**Step 3:**
In tableview UITableViewDataSource cellForRowAt function, add your cell the given way.

```
let cell = tableView.dequeueCell(ofType: YourCellName.self)
cell.yourCellFunction()
return cell
```

**Note 1:** dequeueCell(ofType...) is calling the below function internally. you don't need to use it directly.

```
func dequeueCell<T: UITableViewCell>(ofType type: T.Type) -> T  {
}
```

**Important:** You don't need to provide any "Resporation ID" or "Reuse Identifier" for cell. It works with your cell name.