# CustomTableViewCell yeilding nil?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have the same problem as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29035876/swift-custom-uitableviewcell-label-is-always-nil/32921869#32921869) But have not been able to make their solution work.

Every time this runs:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = commentTableViewCell()

    print("called T")
    if arrayOfComments.count != 0 {
        do {
            let url = URL(string: (arrayOfComments[indexPath.row].user.profileImageUrlString)!)
            let imageData = try Data(contentsOf: url!)
            let image = UIImage(data: imageData)

            cell.dateOfComment.text = "testText"//crash here
        } catch {
            print(error, ": Failed in do block converting image")
        }
    }

    return cell
}
```

I get:

> Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value

CustomCell:

```
import UIKit

class commentTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var dateOfComment: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var commentText: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var profImage: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var username: UILabel!
}
```

Comment: The line `let cell = commentTableViewCell()` is not correct. You need to properly dequeue a cell from the table view. Your way isn't creating the cell from the storyboard (or xib) so none of the outlets are setup, hence the nil.

Comment: Look at any one of the many, many table view tutorials for Swift. You'll find plenty of examples of how to implement the `cellForRowAt` method. This includes the question you linked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set an identifier for your cell and Replace

```
let cell = commentTableViewCell() // this loads the cell class without attached IB outlets
```

with

```
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier:"cellId", for: indexPath) as! commentTableViewCell
```

---

Also this

```
let imageData = try Data(contentsOf: url!)
```

blocks the main thread consider using [SDWebImage](https://github.com/SDWebImage/SDWebImage)

---

For Xib cells in `viewDidLoad`

```
tableView.register(UINib(nibName: "commentTableViewCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "commentCell")
```

And you must have

> commentTableViewCell.swift
>
> commentTableViewCell.xib

For prototype cells

> just set the identifier  without the register as it's done automatically in that case